# Permanently fix the Eclipse error "project description file (.project) is missing"

Tags: eclipse, git

Every time I boot Eclipse I get the error "The project description file (.project) for my project is missing".

As other StackOverflow answers have show, this is easy enough to fix: delete package from Eclipse and import it again. However, if I close and reopen Eclipse the error will be back. I have not found a permanent solution yet.

I have my workspace in my Dropbox, but at some point I decided it was time to start using Git. I don't really get Git but they say you have to put the .project file in your .gitignore because it is computer specific.

This I feel is the origin of the problem, but if I don't do any git related activities (push, commit, etc.) I still get this error.

How do I fix this once and for all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .project is a Eclipse-specific file that tells Eclipse about how the project's struture is placed in the project's hierarchy.

It's normal for this file (and other Eclipse specific files) to not be committed because other people participating on the same project may use other IDEs of their choices (intellij, and so on), so the content committed in your VCS is 'neutral' for IDEs.

When you create a project from inside Eclipse, the .project file shall be created along. But when you import into Eclipse an existing project, there are ways to generate locally the .project , .classpath and other Eclipse-required files. Maven, Gradle and Ant are some examples of tools that do this.

Finally, I recommend to keep these files in .gitignore so the project's contents in VCS will remain neutral to IDEs. So you will not bother other people using other IDEs.

So, the steps are:

- Check out the project
- Generate the eclipse files using maven, ant or gradle. If your project already uses a tool such as these, thats nice
- Check if the project is OK inside eclipse (compiling, no errors)
- Add the newly generated eclipse files to .gitignore
- commit and push the .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

`.project` is *not* machine-specific as long as everyone on your team has the plug-ins installed for that kind of project.  `.classpath` *might* be if you don't do things right. This is *your* project, though, so commit your `.project`.

Keeping `.classpath` clean largely revolves around keeping machine-specific paths and references out of it:

1. Set the project's JRE using an `Execution Environment`. It is an indirect way of saying what version you need, then the IDE figures it out for that machine. The stored value defaults to using the name of your default **Installed JRE** in the preferences, which is very machine-specific.
2. Put the jar files you need into the project, or into another project that this one can refer to. They go into source control as well for the sake of repeatability, unless you're using a tool like Maven, in which case be specific about the version you require where ever you state that dependency and **make sure the relevant M2E plug-ins are installed**.